# Google Analytics: XHR instead of pixel-tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, xmlhttprequest

By default google analytics use pixel-tracking technology to send statistics to server. I can see a piece of code in analytics.js for new image object generating.

```js
ta = function (a) {
        var b = M[u]("img");
        b.width = 1;
        b.height = 1;
        b.src = a;
        return b
    }
```

But a browser loads this image too late, after all images on a page. So using an XHR-request could be a solution. And I fount in analytics.js such piece of code, and it shows what google analytics can send xhr-requests instead of pixel-tracking.

```
"image" == c ? wc(b, d, e) : "xhr" == c && wd(b, d, e) || "beacon" == c && x(b, d, e) || ba(b, d, e)
```

How to make it work this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new [navigator.sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) method by setting the `transport` option to `'beacon'`. Here's an example:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'click', 'download-me', {transport: 'beacon'});
```

And here's the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#transport

`sendBeacon` is a better option than XHR, and GA automatically handles the fallback for browsers that don't support it. If you really wanted to use XHR you could set the `transport` option to `'xhr'`, but I'd recommend using `'beacon'` for all cases. In the future, the `'beacon'` option will likely become the default.